# Substitute for y'

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The problem was:
    $$
x^x=\mathrm{e}^{x-y}
$$
I was able to solve it to(By Implicit differentiation) :
    $$
x^x\left(\ln\left(x\right)+1\right)=\mathrm{e}^{x-y}\left(1-y'\right)
$$
But how do I solve for ***y'*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You have $x^x(\ln(x)+1) = e^{x-y}(1-y')$. Distribute to get $x^x(\ln(x)+1) = e^{x-y} - e^{x-y}y'$.

Now rearrange to get $e^{x-y}y' = e^{x-y}-x^x(\ln(x)+1)$, and now multiplying both sides by $e^{-(x-y)} = e^{y-x}$ will finish the problem.

Comment: How are you able to see things like that?

Comment: You only had one $y'$ involved in the equation, so you just need to move things around in order to isolate it. It becomes an algebra problem, rather than a calculus problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given:
$$x^{x}=e^{x-y}$$
Solve for y:
$$ln{x^x}=x-y$$
$$xlnx=x-y$$
$$y=x-xlnx$$
Differentiate using Product Rule:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=1-[x(\frac{1}{x})+lnx]$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}=-lnx$$